# Why does my find image in image function match non-exact matches?

Tags: java, image, computer-vision, bufferedimage

I am trying to implement various ways of finding image within image. I started with strict match. Let us have `image` for the image we are searching for and `bigImage` for the image we are searching *in*.

```
  /** Finds image in bigImage by exact pixel match (all pixels must be exactly the same color).
   * 
   * @param image the smaller image you want to find
   * @param bigImage the big image you're searching in
   * @return Rect object describing the location where the small image was found. Returns null if nothing was found.
   */
  public static Rect findByExactMatch(BufferedImage image, BufferedImage bigImage) {
    //I marked these final so that I don't accidentally change them later
    final int iw = image.getWidth();
    final int ih = image.getHeight();
    final int bw = bigImage.getWidth();
    final int bh = bigImage.getHeight();

    //Loop from 0 to big image width/height MINUS the small image width/height
    //The MINUS there is, because once you are at the end, the small image overlaps to undefined area
    for(int rect_x=0, mrx=bw-iw; rect_x<mrx; rect_x++) {
      for(int rect_y=0, mry=bh-ih; rect_y<mry; rect_y++) {
          //This is where pixel looping begins
          int x = 0;
          int y = 0;
          for (; x < iw; x++) {
              for (; y < ih; y++) {
                //Get RGB returns 0x00rrggbb
                if(image.getRGB(x, y)!=
                    bigImage.getRGB(x+rect_x, y+rect_y)) {
                  //If the color does not match, break back to the rectangular search
                  //WITHOUT -1 THE VALUE OVERFLOWS ON NEXT ITERATION (damnit, debuged this like an idiot!!!)
                  y = x = Integer.MAX_VALUE-1;
                  break;
                }
              }
          }
          //This statement asks if the loop ended normally
          // - otherwise, the x and y are MAX_INT and greater than iw
          if(x==iw) {
            return Rect.byWidthHeight(rect_x, rect_y, iw, ih); 
          }
      }
    }
    //Nothing found - return null
    return null;
  }
```

As you can see, the function is pretty simple, most of the code are comments. First two loops move *frame* of the location we are comparing, while the inner loops compare small image and the big one at the current offset.

The usage then can look like this:

```
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
     //The small image to search for
     BufferedImage thing = loadFromPath("thing.png");
     //The big image to search in
     BufferedImage screenshot = loadFromPath("screenshot.png");
     if(thing!=null && screenshot!=null) {
       Rect pos = autoclick.ScreenWatcher.findByExactMatch(thing, screenshot);
       if(pos!=null) {
          System.out.println("Found object: "+pos);
          //Draw rectangle on discovered position
          Graphics2D graph = screenshot.createGraphics();
          graph.setColor(Color.RED);
          graph.drawRect(pos.top, pos.left, pos.width, pos.height);
          graph.dispose();
          //Save the file for review
          try {
            ImageIO.write(screenshot, "png", new File("output.png"));
          } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger("wtf goes here?").log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
          }
       }
     }
   }
```

Unfortunately, it does not seem to work (red frame displays the location identified by the program):

[image: searching that failed and found just white area]

When I was complaining to my friend, however, and wanted to show him that the evil code does not wanna work, it worked suddenly:

[image: the case when the match was found]

The important thing to notice is, that **if the first column of image isn't white, it works**. Or so it seems to me.

I made a test project with all necesary files available: https://gist.github.com/Darker/f08b2fbf1795af9ebbe2. By default, it expects 'thing.png' as the `image` and 'screenshot.png' as the `bigImage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your inner match loops (x and y) are miscoded; look at it carefully. You initialize *both* loop variables before the loop, which means when there is no mismatch in the first column, y has been incremented to the value of ih, bypassing the y-loop on all following passes of the x-loop.

One way to fix it would be to move the x and y initialization into their respective for statements (where they belong) and place a label on the `for(rect_y...)` statement. On pixel mismatch, instead of a break, use `continue recty` to abort both x and y-loop. This avoids the need to manipulate x/y and the artificial check after.

```
         for (rect_x ...) {
label:       for (rect_y...) {
                 for (x = 0; ...) {
                     for (y = 0; ....) {
                         if (mismatch) {
                             continue label;
                         }
                      }
                 }
                 return "match";
             }
         }
         return null;
```

To make things less convoluted, you could also refactor the inner two loops into a separate method and simply use `return` to break the loops when a mismatch occurs.

Comment: Thanks. Shame on me. Anyway, I think a solution I'll go for is to only assign the `INTEGER.MAX_VALUE` to the `x` and breaking the inner loop.